# Informatica Stored Procedure Transformation

Tags: transformation, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Is there a way to call a stored procedure transformation which has no input and output parameters defined in the stored procedure? Please advise.

Comment: no, I just need to execute the same stored procedure twice and this will be a part of an existing workflow. so I was thinking to use a mapping/session, in which I can have two pipelines which do exactly the same thing, run the stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks Marek, i think its a simple command that I have to give when calling it in the pre or post SQL, right? like `call procedure_name;`? Please correct if I am wrong. also, I have one more quick question, would it affect the second run of the stored procedure if any error occurs in the middle of the session?

Comment: Yes, the RDBMS I use is Oracle. You mean to say, to create a dummy session and call the stored procedure in the pre and post SQL? If not please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to create a dummy mapping (first create a dummy table in the source which has columns for different data types) and then call the stored procedure in the pre-sql or post-sql for the session.